# Handling exceptions without try block in Python's interactive shell

Tags: python, command-line, exception, interactive-mode

See the title of this question. I want to play with the exception raised in the last command. `_` didn't help me. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Could you provide any code or error traceback or anything we can read to understand what you're talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
import sys
sys.exc_info()
```

It will give you information about the exception. It's a tuple containing the exception type, the exception instance and a traceback object.

Comment: sys.last_value will not work in 3.0, sys.exc_info() will work on 3.0 and 2.x

Comment: sys.last_value works in 2.7 and according to the documentation, it's still there in Python 3.3. However sys.exc_info() won't work outside of an `except` block.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'interactive' happens within Jupyter, check this > [Jupyter magic to handle notebook exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110540/jupyter-magic-to-handle-notebook-exceptions)

It is just beautiful.

If you want to add a sound > [Jupyter / Colab : Play sound with any error in any cell + Play sound after completing long running cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176900/jupyter-colab-play-sound-with-any-error-in-any-cell-play-sound-after-compl/61176901#61176901)